# How can I validate a textbox input to be a positive or negative integer in mvc using dataannotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

User can input positive and negative floating numbers. Currently I am using

```
[Range(0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Only integers are allowed")]
```

but when I entered negative numbers with starting with - sign it give me validation error.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke Its working fine... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you `RangeAttribute` to

```
[Range(double.MaxMinValue, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Only integers are allowed")]
```

Side note: I thing the error message should be `"Only numbers are.."`? Your allowing floating point numbers, not just integers, but if the property your applying this to is typeof `double`, the `RangeAttribute` is not really required.